# How would I build a sql query for this situation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which gives me information on projects. I also have another table where I add comments or updates people log on the projects. The tables are joined on a project number. I will have one for returned for project, and multiple rows returned for comments. What would be the best way to do this? I think if I could achieve something like the following it would be great:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+--+
|  project_Name   | Project_description | Start_date  | Comments |  |
+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+--+
| TestProjectName | TestProjectDesc     | 01/01/2016  | Comment1 |  |
| Null            | Null                | Null        | Comment2 |  |
| Null            | Null                | Null        | Comment3 |  |
+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+--+
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to produce this with a query?

Comment: Is there any reason a normal `select * from project p join project_comments pc on p.id = pc.project_id` won't work?

Comment: Your best bet is to start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `What would be the best way to do this?` <---- do what? What is it you are trying to 'do'? What are you expecting in your output? What are the names of your tables?

Comment: The best way to do this would be outside of sql server, in the presentation layer. Not that it can't be done, even easily, in sql, but this kind of logic in the presentation layer will out perform any sql based solution, and it's the logical place to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Union all` operator and then order it by project number. SQL Query would look something like this

```
SELECT  project_Name, Project_description, Start_date, Comments, Project_Number from Projects
UNION ALL
Select Null, Null, Null, Comment, Project_Number From Comments
Order By Project_Number
```

I don't know the tables names so I cannot create the whole statement well

Comment: Thanks! This is it. It is now being built exactly as I need.

Comment: No problem, I am glad to help. Can you please mark this answer as accepted ? I would like to have more reputation so I can comment on other's answers. @spacerobot